# Start new process as system process

Tags: node.js, process, child-process

Is it possible to start a process out of node, which is not a child process from the node instance but a system process?
If i use child_process, new processes are included in the father process. The problem is, that all other processes will be killed, if the father process is canceled. I want to run the new processes instead the father process is killed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `child.unref()` a try. [According to the node.js documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html):

> If the detached option is set, the child process will be made the leader of a new process group. This makes it possible for the child to continue running after the parent exits.
>
> By default, the parent will wait for the detached child to exit. **To prevent the parent from waiting for a given child, use the child.unref() method**, and the parent's event loop will not include the child in its reference count.

Emphasis mine. So knowing that, you can also pass in `true` to the `detached` option in the options hash when forking:

```
var child = spawn('prg', [], {
        detached: true,
        stdio: [ 'ignore', out, err ]
    });
```

Comment: Thank you! :) I've noticed, that spawn is a bit difficult on Windows. For those who want to use it on Windows, this can be helpful. https://www.npmjs.org/package/win-spawn